# How do I calculate the average slope of an array in Excel?

Tags: excel, finance

I have a series of returns in a column of cells and would like to calculate the average slope calculated from the differences between each return value.

```
Returns:          
0.05              
0.06 
0.04 
0.07 
0.05 
0.06
```

I do not want to create a row for the differences because I have more columns of return streams beside the one above. I'm looking for a non-vba solution.

The answer I'm looking for is shown below:

```
Required Value: = Sum of slopes/No. of periods
Ans: -0.001666666
```

Cheers!

Comment: How'd you get to `.0016666` with the numbers you have?

Comment: I get a negative `-0.0016667`

Comment: He appears to be calculating the difference between the NEXT value and the last value, adding that to a rolling total, then dividing by the number of entries once complete.  For that, you should get -0.0016 (repeating).

Comment: Sorry guys, yes, it's supposed to be -0.0016. Just edited the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At risk of being controversial:-

```
=(A7-A2)/COUNT(A3:A7)
```

because (A7-A6)+(A6-A5)...+(A3-A2) = A7-A2 and because there are only 5 differences between the 6 numbers, so my answer is 0.002..

Comment: Oh yeah, a better implementation. But I'd still use six in the denominator and take the reverse slop for my needs (hence -0.0016). Thanks, though!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a SUMPRODUCT() to get the sum of the differences then divide it by the count:

This one subtracts the lower from the upper:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$6-$A$3:$A$7)/COUNT(A2:A7)
```

If you want it the other way around, by subtracting the upper from the lower then use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$3:$A$7-$A$2:$A$6)/COUNT(A2:A7)
```

[image]